# Facing an import error in Azure SQL when trying to import a .bacpac file

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

I have exported a database into a `.bacpac` file and I'm trying to import it, but I get this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Could not import package.
>
> Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'SRC_MBR_ID' in table 'dbo.Dbt_tb_Associate_MemberBasic' is of a type that is invalid for us

How can I ignore this index creation at time of the import?

Comment: Well - what is the structure (columns and their datatypes) of that table `dbo.Dbt_tb_Associate_MemberBasic`? What **datatype** is column `SRC_MBR_ID` ?

Comment: "That is invalid for us"? Is that *really* what it says?

Comment: @marc_s data type is string with max for SRC_MBR_ID but i know that will not create the index and I also want to avoid this index creation , so how it is possible in times of import that's my question

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can install a [SQL Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) Developer Edition on a computer or VM, import the bacpac to that SQL Server instance instead, proceed to drop the table not compatible with Azure SQL (dbo.Dbt_tb_Associate_MemberBasic), export the database as bacpac and then import it to Azure SQL.

A better option will be to use Azure Data Migration Assistant (DMA) to perform [an assessment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assesssqlonprem?view=sql-server-ver16) of the database once you have successfully imported to a SQL Server 2022 instance, resolve any incompatibilities found on the assessment, then use DMA to [easily migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-ver16) to Azure SQL. You will get no more surprises importing bacpacs.

Comment: could you please guide me a little bit more about "proceed to drop the table" how i can do this drop in times of import

Comment: I do not mean to do that on the import to Azure SQL. My suggestion is to import the database to a local SQL Server on-premises and once imported to the on-premises instance drop the offending table. From there you can use DMA to migrate the database to Azure SQL or you can export the database as bacpac. Use the newly created bacpac to Import it to Azure SQL.

Comment: I tried to import it on sql server 2022 got same error

Comment: On what flavor of SQL instance was the bacpac created from?

Comment: Hyper scale instance

Comment: btw I followed https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/editing-a-bacpac-file/ba-p/368931 but got no luck

Comment: If the bacpac was created with Hyperscale that is an important information. Importing bacpacs created on Hyperscale usually fail for many reasons as you can read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/manage-hyperscale-database?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#limitations-for-reverse-migration. Copy the hyperscale database inside the hyperscale, on the newly created database originated from the copy operation, remove the offending table and proceed to create the bacpac again. Please do not forget to mention you are using Hyperscale on your questions in the future,

Comment: I tried to import it in hyperscale instance btw regarding offending tables recreation is not possible cause that was deleted after taking the backup

Comment: Create a support ticket on Azure so they can help you import it to Azure SQL or back to Hyperscale. Hyperscale has a special hardware has many things not supported that are usually supported on Azure SQL. At the same time Hyperscale has features not available on other PaaS SQL flavors.